# Placing text into cells in number field using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2.  I have an attribute table with a long integer field, but I have a few cells in this field without values.  I want to put "N/A" in these cells.  So, the field remains a long integer field in which most cells do indeed have long integers, but a few cells need to have N/A.

Is this possible?

Comment: It depends on the data source format.  Shapefiles don't support numeric NULLs, but file and enterprise geodatabases do. And that's what you need, a NULL value.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to store text values in an integer field in a table.

However, depending on how your attribute table is stored, and how you're viewing the data, it may be possible to *display* "N/A" for those records where the field is blank. For example, if you want to label these features with their values in this table, you could use a labeling expression written in Python to use the field value for the label if the value is an integer, but use "N/A" if the value is blank.

Comment: I appreciate your response.